# determine the address of the location using the Google Maps Geocoding API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

i had problem on saving the address in variable when i use google map api

i try to save it in global variable and then calling these variable with console.log

```
<script>
    var x;
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.191315760031543, 31.189079340815315),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
            var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address + "\r\nLatitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "\r\nLongitude: " + e.latLng.lng());
                            x=results[1].formatted_address;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    }
    console.log(x);
</script>
```

Geocoding Service: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key`enter code here`

Comment: Hello Selvia, welcome to SO. Did the read the last links of your question? It seems they have useful info.

Comment: yes, you need to have an apikey to access google maps api. it is must now.

Comment: Also, geocoding is asynchronous, so your `console.log(x)` won't work where it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's **required** to include an **[API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)** to authenticate all Maps API requests. As per the error you provided, it indicates that there is no API key included in the script that loads the JavaScript API.

Kindly include the API key like this:

```
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
    </script>
```

Then replace the text YOUR_API_KEY with your valid API key.

Please also note that it is recommended to initialize your map by specifying a [`callback`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API) parameter. Please see more info about that [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).